# Como alterar a cor da linha da tabela(php) de acordo com o valor?

Tags: tabela-html

```html
<?php 
include_once("func/functions.php"); // Chama o arquivo de funções

function diaria($codmot,$periodo)
{
 $data =  (explode(" - ",$periodo));
 $datIni =  date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data[0]));
 $datFin =  date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data[1]));

 $conn_datapar = connect();
 $sql = "SP_TI_DIARIAS_E_LANCHES $codmot,'$datIni 00:00:00', '$datFin 23:59:59', 117";
 $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn_datapar, $sql); 

 while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  $ficha = $row["CODFIC"];
  $data = $row["DATREF"]->format('d-m-Y H:i');
  $obs = $row["OBSERV"];
  $valor = $row["VLRADI"];

  echo "
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>".$ficha."</td>
     <td>".$data."</td>
     <td>".$obs."</td>
     <td>R$".$valor."</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  ";
 }
}
```

Boa tarde galera!
Estou precisando muito da ajuda de vocês.
Tenho uma tabela(php),preenchida com informações do BD,preciso que esses resultados,quando o valor da .$valor., for negativo,a linha fique vermelha,quando for positivo fique verde.
OBS: Usei a grid,e deu certo ,ficou exatamente como eu queria,porém a tabela fica com melhor visualização e meu chefe, quer que seja feito com tabela.
Alguém sabe como me ajudar ?
Desde ja agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Pode postar o código PHP que gera a tabela?

Comment: To quebrando a cabeça com isso tem 2 dias

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu seu problema não deixe de marcá-la como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e posrque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1):

**Dentro do while** faça um `if else` para setar a cor dependendo do valor da variável `$valor` e coloque na linha da tabela `<tr style='background-color:".$color."'>`

```
$valor = $row["VLRADI"];
// decide a cor do fundo das linhas
if($valor>0){
  $color="green";
}else{
  $color="red";
}

    echo "
        <tbody>
            <tr style='background-color:".$color."'>
                <td>".$ficha."</td>
                <td>".$data."</td>
                <td>".$obs."</td>
                <td>R$".$valor."</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    ";
```

> Nada impede de se usar classes com CSS

**CSS**

```
  .verde{
     background-color:green;
  }

  .vermelha{
     background-color:red;
  }
```

**PHP**

```
$valor = $row["VLRADI"];

if($valor>0){
  $class="verde";
}else{
  $class="vermelha";
}

    echo "
        <tbody>
            <tr class='".$class."'>
                <td>".$ficha."</td>
                <td>".$data."</td>
                <td>".$obs."</td>
                <td>R$".$valor."</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    ";
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!
Você me mostrou o erro, eu estava colocando a classe no td ao invés de colocar no tr.
Valew mesmo pela força.